# iframe doesn't getting hidden using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, show-hide

In my page I have a div with another div and an iframe as shown below.

```
<div class="v_dissc_tab" id="tabs-1">
    <div id="publicevent">
    <div class="crtraone" style="margin-left:800px;">
        <button onclick="addpublic()">Add New</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td><b>Programme</b></td>
            <td><b>Scheduled Start Time</b></td>
            <td><b>Scheduled End Time</b></td>
            <td><b>Amount</b></td>
            <td><b>Status</b></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <?php if($publicnum>0)
             {

             }
             else 
             { ?>                                                                          
                        <td colspan=6>                                                                
                          <?php echo "No any public channel programmes";?>                                                      
                        </td>
            <?php }?>
        </tr>
        </table>
          </div>
    </div>
    <iframe id="calendarframe" style="width: 100%;height:600px;display:none;" src="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/channel/viewbookings">
        </iframe>
</div>
```

On page loading, the div with id `publicevent` will be shown and the iframe is hidden. When I click on *Add New button*, the iframe will be loaded. Inside iframe I am loading another page which contains a button

```
<button onclick="managepublic()">Manage Public Events</button>
```

On clicking this button, I want to show the div with id `publicevent` and want to hide the iframe (as when the page is firstly loaded). Shown below is `managepublic()`.

```
function managepublic()
    {
        location.reload();  // not making any changes
        //$('#publicevent').show(); Tried with this also
       //$('#calendarframe').hide();
    }
```

Can anyone help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: cannot make a fiddle with a iframe, cross-origin policy. Check the code snippet in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code snippet.

You are referring elements of `<iframe>`'s parent.

```
function managepublic(){
    $('#calendarframe', window.parent.document).hide(250, function() {
        $('#publicevent', window.parent.document).show();
    });
}
```

Or

```
function managepublic(){
        window.parent.$('#calendarframe').hide(250, function() {
        window.parent.$('#publicevent').show();
    });

}
```

Or Change the order of the hide events.

```
function managepublic(){
        window.parent.$('#publicevent').show();
        window.parent.$('#calendarframe').hide();

}
```

**Note** :

- For this to work, parent must have jQuery included.
- It won't work if parent is in different domain.

Answer (score 1):

dont' use location.reload ,use only following code

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script> 

      function managepublic()
            {

               $('#publicevent').show(); 
               $('#calendarframe').hide();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

> On clicking this button, I want to show the div with id publicevent
>   and want to hide the iframe (as when the page is firstly loaded).

Check if this helps.

```
$('iframe').attr( "src", "http://www.apple.com/");

$('iframe').load(function() {
    $('iframe').show()
    $('#loaded').hide();


});

$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#loaded').show();
    $('iframe').hide();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/CPadm/1050/)

Comment: nop..fiddle is not working properly. It is not hiding the iframe.

Comment: the `iframe` is hided after click the `div` button. This work at my pc. If it does not work at yours, then I would guess this is your browser problem